# Reading JPEG in ffmpeg

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm trying to get ffmpeg to encode several individual JPEG images into a video on Android. I've successfully built it for Android (see the configuration string at the end of this post).

I can encode an h.263+ video with randomly generated frame content, and ffmpeg otherwise appears to work well.

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527584/ffmpeg-jpeg-file-to-avframe) suggests that the following code should be sufficient to load an image into an `AvFrame`:

```
// Make sure we have the codecs
av_register_all();

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
int ret = av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, imageFileName, NULL, 0, NULL);

if (ret != 0) {
    printf("Can't open image file '%s': code %d, %s",
        imageFileName, ret, strerror(AVERROR(ret)));
}
```

The above returns the correct absolute file path and error:

> Failed '/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG083.jpg': code -1094995529, Unknown error: 1094995529

Incidentally, if I omit `av_register_all()`, it returns with error **2**.

I've compiled ffmpeg with the following arguments:

> > ./configure --target-os=linux 
> >         --prefix=$PREFIX 
> >         --enable-cross-compile 
> >         --extra-libs="-lgcc" 
> >         --arch=arm 
> >         --cc=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 
> >         --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- 
> >         --nm=$PREBUILT/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm 
> >         --sysroot=$PLATFORM 
> >         --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " 
> >         --enable-shared 
> >         --enable-static 
> >         --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" 
> >         --disable-everything 
> >         --enable-demuxer=mov 
> >         --enable-demuxer=h264 
> >         --disable-ffplay 
> >         --enable-protocol=file 
> >         --enable-avformat 
> >         --enable-avcodec 
> >         --enable-decoder=mjpeg 
> >         --enable-decoder=png 
> >         --enable-parser=h264 
> >         --enable-encoder=h263 
> >         --enable-encoder=h263p 
> >         --disable-network 
> >         --enable-zlib 
> >         --disable-avfilter 
> >         --disable-avdevice

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: By the way, the error code is AVERROR_INVALIDDATA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error suggests that the decoder needed for JPEG was not built along with ffmpeg. I believe enabling `mjpeg` is sufficient in order for it to work, but out of frustration I simply enabled everything and it worked.

I would suggest adding `--enable-decoder=mjpeg` to the configuration string and rebuilding the library with NDK for Android. If that doesn't work, remove `--disable-everything` and individually remove incompatible components until it successfully compiles (I believe just adding `--disable-indev` worked for Android).

Comment: Sure enough, after `av_open_input_file()`, executing `av_find_best_stream()` yields the "mjpeg" video codec with the correct dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Note: in addition to "mjpeg" muxer/demuxer/parser, you need "image2" muxer/demuxer.

Answer (score 0):

As [No One](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050232/no-one) wrote you need to enable mjpeg and image2 when calling `./configure`

```
--enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=image2
```

I've just checked it with my code that reads jpg.