# Can't load ImageFile [FFmpeg on Android]

Tags: android, ffmpeg

My purpose is same here

 [FFmpeg: Jpeg file to AVFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527584/ffmpeg-jpeg-file-to-avframe)


but, I was stumble before that loading file.
at

```
if(av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, imageFileName, NULL, 0, NULL)!=0)
{
    printf("Can't open image file '%s'\n", imageFileName);
    return NULL;
}
```

This point return always Can't open `image file /sdcard/test.jpg` on Emulator(ICS) and real device(Froyo).

・Of cause wrote `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in Manufest
・Change the file path is all failed `sdcard/test.jpg`,`sdcard/test.jpeg`,`mnt/sdcard/test.jpeg`,`/mnt`...

・My FFmpeg ver0.8.12

And Video files are passed this point(FLV,MEPGVIDEO..)

Anything else?