# FFMPEG in realtime system, memory allocation concerns

Tags: memory-management, ffmpeg, real-time

For our project, we plan to use FFMPEG to do real time decoding and encoding. As a result, we have to allocate several objects such as AVCodecContext, AVFrame, AVPacket for each frame we read in. Because this is done on a real time system, we are concerned if there will be memory fragmentation with the repeated memory allocation and de-allocation. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed to allocate those objects for every frame. Single AVCodecContext, AVFrame & AVPacket is enough to process a stream. When it needs to process the sequence of packet and frame we can reuse the same AVFrame ([av_frame_unref](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structAVFrame.html#:%7E:text=AVFrame%20is%20typically%20allocated%20once%20and%20then%20reused%20multiple%20times%20to%20hold%20different%20data%20(e.g.%20a%20single%20AVFrame%20to%20hold%20frames%20received%20from%20a%20decoder).%20In%20such%20a%20case%2C%20av_frame_unref()%20will%20free%20any%20references%20held%20by%20the%20frame%20and%20reset%20it%20to%20its%20original%20clean%20state%20before%20it%20is%20reused%20again.)) & AVPacket ([av_packet_unref](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/structAVPacket.html#:%7E:text=The%20semantics%20of%20data%20ownership%20depends%20on%20the%20buf%20field.%20If%20it%20is%20set%2C%20the%20packet%20data%20is%20dynamically%20allocated%20and%20is%20valid%20indefinitely%20until%20a%20call%20to%20av_packet_unref()%20reduces%20the%20reference%20count%20to%200.)) object.
But don't forget to free all the objects at the end (all of them has custom delete functions).

This tutorial explains the thing very well with example code [Learn FFmpeg libav the Hard Way](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#learn-ffmpeg-libav-the-hard-way)

Also, you can check out the official [FFmpeg example page](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.1/examples.html) for more complex ones.

Comment: In our case, we have a series of PNG files coming in, and we have decode them and encode them as a video stream. For the decoding part, don't we need a new AVCodecContext for each PNG file? Pardon my ignorance, I'm still new to FFMPEG

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552057/10334333 they trying to combine a series of Jpeg but you can also use this code for PNG with little changes.